# GDAL second order polynomial fails in Python but first order and thin plate spline work fine

Tags: python, gdal, qgis-3, gdalwarp

I have Python code that will automatically georeference drone images regardless of overlap and without SfM software.  The code runs without error when I set my transformation type to a first order polynomial but I am unhappy with the georeferencing.  I can alter my code to use a thin plate spline transformation and this also runs without error.  I would like to test the output of a second order polynomial.  When I change the arguments to gdal_warp to apply a second order polynomial I get the following error:

```
Error Info:
Failed to compute GCP transform: Transform is not solvable
```

Here is the relevant code for the working TPS transformation:

```
kwargs = {'format': 'GTiff', 'tps': True, 'dstSRS':'EPSG:4326'}
```

and here is the relevant code for the working first order polynomial transformation:

```
kwargs = {'format': 'GTiff', 'polynomialOrder':1,'dstSRS':'EPSG:4326'}
```

And here is the relevant code for the failed second order transformation:

```
kwargs = {'format': 'GTiff', 'polynomialOrder':2,'dstSRS':'EPSG:4326'}
```

If I try a second order transformation in QGIS with less than 6 GCPs QGIS complains and returns an error message that I need 6 GCPs for this transformation.  I am feeding 6 GCP into GDAL.  See [this link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/395999/gdal-gcp-python-georeferencing-fails-to-perform-thin-plate-spline-transformation) for some past trouble shooting issues and details on the project.

Why is GDAL/Python not allowing me to do a second order polynomial transformation?

Comment: Can you use second order if you add your ground control points into GeoTIFF manually with gdal_translate and then run gdalwarp with -order 2?

Comment: Yes, that is how I am doing it.  I write the GCPs to a list, then iterate the list ap add gdal.GCP.  After the GCP are added to the geoTiff I use gdal.Warp with my transformations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the suggestion from @user30184 feeding 8 gcps into the process solved the issue and allowed me to do a second order transformation.